How to write data into an address in MIPS?
I'm currently trying to develop a monocycle MIPS in TKgate 1.8, when creating the Memory Data and attempting to implement the lw and sw instructions, I can't figure out "how" to use the WriteData input, just that it has to be used when MemWrite is enabled and to write the data from WriteData into the Address (provided by the "Address" input)
Any help and explanation?
Memory Data Module
I've tried looking up for ways to build this module, but I can't seem to find any "inside module" structure of components, I can't seem to figure it out

If you are planning to run some MIPS machine code on it, then you'll need to provide or identify some storage to back the writes and reads.
And the property you need is to be able to later read earlier writes.
So, for example, if there is a write of a word value 0x12345678 to memory location 0x10010000, then a later read (of a word from that memory location) must return that data value.
A read returns the last value written to each location — that is the definition of (computer) memory.  While a write overwrites whatever was previously stored there with a (potentially) new value.
(It should be clear that you'll need to be able to handle multiple memory locations, identified by different addresses.)
In formal terms, we're looking at a well-behaved lens, which has the properties of reading what was last written, defined formally by some rules: PutGet says if we put first, then get, we get back what we put;  while PutPut says that the last put wins, overwriting earlier puts.

There may be some addresses that are off limits.  Consult your environment.
You might implement as a hash (key-value) of (key:) address & (value:) value, or an array of value indexed by address, which is sort of what the hardware does.
